# Lost garage band files can I build my project on Xcode?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, xcode, data-recovery, garageband

So it’s been a year since my computer crashed and corrupted my hard drive. I lost most of my audio files on GarageBand. I have one project I really want back and in the file it has 2 audio tracks still standing plus project data as well. Anyway I can use that on Xcode to build my project back together?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Xcode is not the tool to help you with your dilemma. If you recorded all the tracks, you’ll be out of luck unless you can locate other copies or a backup.

Where is the hard drive from a year back? If it’s in storage and not used, we might be able to suggest some already developed data recovery software.